# Problem with date picker code

Tags: iphone, datepicker, uipickerview

I recently added a feature to my medical app that calculates a patient's age from an entered date. If the age is zero, then the date picker displays January 1, 1950 as a default starting date for entry of the date of birth. The code works fine on iOS 4.0+ on iPhone and iPad hardware. However, when testing just prior to submission for an app update, I found the date picker crashing on my first-generation iPod, which I keep for testing iOS 3.1.3. I narrowed down the following code as the culprit, which sets the default date for the date picker:

```
    if (age == 0) {
        NSDateFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [myFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yy"];
        NSDate *initialDate = [myFormatter dateFromString:@"January/01/1950"];
        [picker setDate:initialDate animated:YES];
    }
```

The log from the iPod shows the following two lines after the crash:

```
<Warning>: *** Assertion failure in -[UIDatePickerView _updateBitsForDate:andReload:animateIfNeeded:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-984.38/UIDatePicker.m:908
```

and

```
<Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: date'
```

I would appreciate any help in understanding why this crash occurs only on the older device, and how to solve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The _updateBitsForDate:andReload:animateIfNeeded: looks to be a custom method. Post the code for help.

Comment: @MSgambel: `_updateBitsForDate:andReload:animateIfNeeded:` is an internal Apple method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [tr35-10](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) standard, your date format should be `MMMM/dd/yyyy`.

You should also [cache formatters for efficiency](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW10).

Comment: Thanks very much. Changing "M/d/yy" to "MMMM/dd/yyyy" in the code fixed the problem. I suppose iOS 4 is more forgiving here than iOS 3. This issue also illustrated to me the value of testing updates on all supported hardware.